# How to load black white image into metal texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I use two methods to load black white image texture in metal as below:

```
 //1.
    mtltexture01 = [textureLoader newTextureWithName:@"texture02"
                                         scaleFactor:1.0
                                              bundle:nil
                                             options:textureLoaderOptions
                                               error:&error];



 //2.
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"texture02"];

    mtltexture01 = [textureLoader newTextureWithCGImage:img.CGImage options:textureLoaderOptions error:&error];
```

but both crash, the error log is

> "Error Domain=MTKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=0 "Image decoding
> failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image decoding failed,
> MTKTextureLoaderErrorKey=Image decoding failed}",

how to fix this issue? Also if I load the colorful image into metal, it runs.[image]

Comment: suggesting to exchange line 99 and 104 with each other (# from your screenshot).
In 99 you load a texture from bundle, then you load an UIImage, then you load again the texture but from stack. Did you intend to do any kind of fallback mechanism for your loader?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id<MTLTexture>)textureWithName:(NSString*)imgname UsingDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device {

     MTKTextureLoader* textureLoader = [[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device];

     NSDictionary *textureLoaderOptions = @{
         MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureUsage : @(MTLTextureUsageShaderRead),
         MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureStorageMode : @(MTLStorageModePrivate)
     };

     return [textureLoader newTextureWithName:imgname
         scaleFactor:1.0
         bundle:nil
         options:textureLoaderOptions
         error:nil];
}
```

and in your metal configurations

```
id<MTLTexture> mtltexture01;

mtltexture01 = [self textureWithName:@"texture02" UsingDevice:device];
```

Keep in mind `texture02` is a filename and the file needs to be available in your apps assets. You can store the image as MTLTexture into your asset in Xcode and so the conversion is done at build time.

Also check if the image contains at least proper opacity and is one of PNG, JPEG, or TIFF format. There is known loader trouble when textures contain only gray/ black colors and 0% transparency is used.

later integrate your texture to the renderEncoder/commandEncoder

screenshot: Xcode Assets Texture Configurator
[image]

Comment: Thanks guys. What is then meaning of "There is known loader trouble when textures contain only gray/ black colors and 0% transparency is used."?

Comment: the loader is able to convert images into mtlkits native texture (buffer) format.
read about here if you need to make a custom loader 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures
I would go with PNG images because of quality and you cant make so much mistakes as with TIFF and JPEG.. that way you know at least if its properly working. But hey drop it as asset in your asset catalog and declare it there as MTLTexture. Easiest way to check if the format is accepted

Comment: I am not a assets catalog expert because doing the most image processing programmatically in my apps. If needed. worth a other question. Good luck

Comment: So do you process the metal texture by MTLTextureDescriptor class?

Comment: Yes i do but that may be a total overdo for you just to load an image in texture buffer. I do it because some of my textures are dynamical and my visualisation is showing real time data.

Comment: Okay，I understand，thanks very much. Maybe I will try it .